# Sympy: can I get an explicit print of a builtin function?

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

What I'm trying to do is basically ask sympy to tell me exactly what mathematical formula is behind some of its builtin functions, since I have been struggling quite a lot with naming conventions, and I'd like to check that I'm using the function I'm supposed to.

My case would be for example with the [builtin Bessel functions](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/special.html#sympy.functions.special.bessel.jn) `jn`: [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Spherical_Bessel_functions), j<sub>0</sub>(x)=sin(x)/x, and I'm inclined to agree having solved that simple-case differential equation by hand.
However, when I ask sympy if `jn(0, x)-sin(x)/x==0` the query returns `False`.
Running `simplify` does nothing but take up time, and I wouldn't know what else to do since `factor` and `expand` at most move the x to be a common denominator and `evalf` gives back the function in terms of yet another builtin function.

Since higher-order functions tend to be a lot more complicated than this, it would be really useful to find out which builtins correspond to what I'm looking for.
I'll be grateful for any link to resources that might help.

Using python3.10.6, sympy 1.9, running on Kubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in `help()` function to read the documentation associated to a given SymPy object, or you can explore the [documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html).

By reading the documentation with `help(jn)`, we can find the description and a few examples, one of which points out to what you'd like to achieve:

```
print(expand_func(jn(0, x)))
# out: sin(x)/x
```

Edit: looking back at your question, you used: `jn(0, x)-sin(x)/x==0`.
With SymPy there are two kinds of equality testing:

- Structural equality, performed with the `==` operator: you are asking SymPy to compare the expression trees. Clearly, `jn(0, x)-sin(x)/x` is structurally different then `0`, because at this stage `jn(0, x)` has not been "expanded".
- Mathematical equality: generally speaking, two expressions are mathematically equivalent if `expr1 - expr2` is equal to 0. So, with the above example we can write: `expand_func(jn(0, x)) - sin(x)/x` which will results to 0. Or, we can use the `equals()` method: `expand_func(jn(0, x)).equals(sin(x) / x)` which will return True. Please, read the documentation about `equals` to better understand its quirks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, `expand_func` is what I'd been searching for. I really don't understand why it's not a method of the function object itself, and, even worse, the `expand` method just returns the unexpanded function.

Comment: It is also a method: `jn(0, x).expand(func=True)`. See the `expand` docstring which explains the optional expand hints.